# Python function that returns true if 2 integers are coprime

Tags: python, primes, number-theory

I need some help to find my bugs in this function:

```
def is_coprime(num_1, num_2):
    """Function that returns true if 2 integers are coprime. """
    if num_1 > num_2:
        small = num_2
    else:
        small = num_1
    for i in range(1, small + 1):
        if ((num_1 % i == 0) and (num_2 % i != 0)):
            gcd = i
        if (gcd == 1):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Hope the indentation isn't so bad. I think my mistake is in the if-condition, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: This Probably a better question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "Hope the indentation isn't so bad" - it is Python, indentation is crucial :-)

Comment: If you have a specific problem with the code, you should edit that into the question. Currently you do not indicate what the actual problem is.

Comment: "to find my bugs" - please add a sample input and expected output to see where the bugs are

Comment: `(num_2 % i != 0)`? Think about that... You're saying that if it doesn't evenly divide, it should be ... the gcd?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Code Review is only for code that [already functions correctly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). "Code Review aims to help improve working code. If you are trying to figure out why your program crashes or produces a wrong result, ask on Stack Overflow instead."

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables in different moments. Use `print()` also to display which part of code is executed. It is called `print debuging`. I see two possible problems - first: mentioned `(num_2 % i != 0)`, second: indentation - you shouldn't check `gcd == 1` inside `for`-loop because this way you for `i = 1` always you get `gcd = 1` and you check `if (gcd == 1):` - so you get `True`

Comment: I see third problem: better declare `gcd` with some value before `for`-loop because in some situations you can check `if gcd == 1:` when it not declaret yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this approach:

```
def divisors(x):
    return {i for i in range(2, x//2 + 1) if not x % i}

def coprime(x, y):
    return divisors(x).isdisjoint(divisors(y))
```

How does it work? divisors(x) returns the set f all divisors of a number greater than 1.
The coprie(x, y) function check, if given sets are disjoint.

Comment: Does `range(2, x+1)` need to go to `x+1` -- can't it be limited to `x//2 + 1` and save some divisions?

Answer (score 1):

Coprime can be done with math.gcd like this:

```
import math

def is_coprime(x, y):
    return math.gcd(x, y) == 1

is_coprime(39, 115)
True

is_coprime(115*89,115)                                                                                                                             
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your algorithm is bad.  Let's walk through a simple example, first assume:

```
num_1 = 2
num_2 = 3
small = 2
```

Running these values through your loop:

```
for i in range(1, small + 1):
    if num_1 % i == 0 and num_2 % i != 0:
        gcd = i
```

First iteration:

```
i = 1
2 % 1 == 0 and 3 % 1 == 0
```

Second (and final) iteration:

```
i = 2
2 % 2 = 0 and 3 % 2 != 0
    gcd = 2
```

Wrong answer!  The gcd(2, 3) == 1

Assuming you don't want to use the built-in `math.gcd()` as @oppressionslayer suggests, we can look up GCD in Wikipedia and use the [recursive binary algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm).  Since we only want to know if the numbers are coprime, we can shortcut one of the statements in that algorithm (even-even test) and simply return `False`:

```
def coprime(u, v):

    # simple cases (termination)
    if u == v:
        return u == 1

    if u == 0:
        return v == 1

    if v == 0:
        return u == 1

    # look for factors of 2
    if ~u & 1:  # u is even
        if v & 1:  # v is odd
            return coprime(u >> 1, v)

        return False

    if ~v & 1:  # v is even, u is odd
        coprime(u, v >> 1)

    # reduce larger argument
    if u > v:
        return coprime(u - v, v)

    return coprime(v - u, u)
```

Some simple tests:

```
print(coprime(2, 3))  # True
print(coprime(21, 24))  # False
print(coprime(39, 115))  # True
print(coprime(115*89, 115))  # False
```